# Where do I purchase a Windows 10 product key online?

Tags: windows-10

I feel like an idiot asking this, but where can I buy a Windows 10 product key for a clean install online? I've googled for half an hour but I always end up on the info pages trying to shove an upgrade down my throat. I am not upgrading.

Is it even possible to purchase this online? Or do I have to order a physical copy and wait days to get it shipped to me, packed in cardboard, plastic and other types of non-virtual materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to Microsoft.com select Store from the Microsoft home page should do the trick.  Go to the bottom of - http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/cat/Windows/categoryID.70036700 and shows it as $199.00 - Just keep going as you have the option to "Buy Windows 10" and download right away - Not Upgrade.

Comment: I am not sure the reason you indicate "not upgrade" when Windows 10 cannot be purchased as an upgrade only a stand-alone license.

Comment: I am confused by your comment? Go to Microsoft.com / Store / Software / Windows / Go to the bottom of the page..  See either Home or Pro..  Select one..  "Buy Windows 10 (Download)" is button to be selected..

Comment: Windows 10 can only be purchased as a stand-alone license.  Using the term "not upgrade" indicates an upgrade license exists which is not the case.

Comment: The original poster stated: "Clean install" and not upgrade..

Comment: Your last statement still does not make sense to me for the reasons I explained.  Technically an upgrade does a clean install, applications and personal files are just moved to another location, then transferred back.

Comment: Not to debate you - but I disagree.  When I think of a clean install, I mean the drive is wiped (using Gparted or similar tool) and you start with the install of Windows and then add the other applications afterward.